# Theorems of linear algebra that appear "algebraic" but depend on topology

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, topological-vector-spaces

Ideas of limit, approximation, and density can be used to prove some results about linear transforms on a real or complex vector space. For example, we can prove that any linear transform satisfies its own characteristics equation by observing that this is ture for diagonalisable matrices, and then argue by density of diagonalisable matrices and continuity of determinant.

Another example is the fact that two matrices $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial. Again, assume at first that $A$ is invertible and use the approximation $A + \epsilon I$ when this is not the case.

However, it turns out that, many of such results, including the ones above, can be proven in a purely algebraic way, without reference to limit and continuity, and to be true for different other base fields without topology. (And, perhaps, giving better insight sometimes.)

So, my question is, are there any results in linear algebra that appear purely algebraic but must require some topology and limit to prove or very difficult to prove without topology?

Comment: The main difficulty of answering your question has to do with the word "must".

Comment: Yes, I have now made some edits. But there are certainly things which need to be proven using some "topological" method, for example the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: A particularly spectacular example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473630/set-of-linear-transformations-which-always-produce-a-basis-generalising-beyond

Comment: Every square matrix of odd order has a real eigenvalue?

Comment: It was possibly for $charpoly(AB)=charpoly(BA)$, I used that there was an homomorphism $M_n(\Bbb{Z}[t_1,\ldots,t_{2 n^2}])$ to $M_n(R)$ where $R$ contains the entries of $A,B$, so the complex theorem (where topological arguments are welcome) implied the algebraic theorem thus the theorem over any commutative ring.

Comment: @reuns What is the homomorphism?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes that is a good example.

Comment: There is an homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}[t_1,\ldots,t_{2 n^2}]$ to the subring generated by $1$ and the entries of $A,B$. And since  $\Bbb{Z}[t_1,\ldots,t_{2 n^2}]$ can be embedded as a subring of $\Bbb{C}$..

Comment: @reuns Oh I see - that's where the number $2n^2$ comes from. Thank you!